# My Angular Routing is nearly identical to the W3schools example, why is it not working?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-routing

So I was trying some basic experimentation in Angular Routing.  This is a near perfect copy and paste from the W3Schools Angular Routing example.  But it doesn't work, except for the "purchase.html" link which isn't really Angular Routing.

I'm sorry to dump the whole program here, but I really have no idea where the error is.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app = "myApp">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style = "text-align: center;">
     
      <li><a href="#/!">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!chars">Characters</a></li>
      <li><a href="purchase.html">Purchase</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div ng-view></div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    templateUrl : "about.htm"
  })
  .when("/chars", {
    templateUrl : "chars.htm"
  })
  .when("/contact", {
    templateUrl : "contact.htm"
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The content of the ng-view div does not change, even though I have corresponding htm files in the same folder, but "ng-view" just doesn't change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console? I suspect this is a CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the above HTML file is being run as-is on a browser the file access will be blocked by CORS policy.

In order to run that file, you can:

- Install `http-server` globally

  ```
  npm install -g http-server
  ```
- Run `http-server` command in the directory where your index file is
- This would host all files in that directory in a local server setup (default port :8080)
- The files would be listed in a similar way to the following image
  [image: HTML file - server file listing]
- Clicking on the file corresponding to one where you are using routing should now have functional routing (provided all file paths are correct)

Hope this helped.